# Разбор XML структуры (преобразовать в "Breadcrumbs" - хлебные крошки)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

**Есть XML файл:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='WINDOWS-1251' ?>
  <categories>
    <category id="20001" >Сетевое оборудование</category>
    <category id="20002" >Контроль доступа</category>
    <category id="20003" >Видеонаблюдение</category>
    <category id="20004" >Источники питания</category>
    <category id="20011"  parentId="20004" >Аккумуляторы</category>
    <category id="20012"  parentId="20003" >Аналоговые видеокамеры</category>
    <category id="20013"  parentId="20002" >Считыватели</category>
    <category id="21247"  parentId="20001" >GOAL city</category>
    <category id="20326"  parentId="20013" >Komkom</category>
    <category id="20400"  parentId="20012" >HikVision</category>
    <category id="20618"  parentId="20011" >ITV</category>
    <category id="20619"  parentId="20011" >ISS</category>
    <category id="20620"  parentId="20011" >DSSL</category>
</categories>
```

**Нужно сделать разбор его структуры в виде "хлебных крошек" получив текстовые строки, вот так...:**

Сетевое оборудование > GOAL city > 21247
Контроль доступа > Считыватели > Komkom > 20326
Видеонаблюдение > Аналоговые видеокамеры > HikVision > 20400
Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ITV > 20618
Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ISS > 20619
Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > DSSL > 20620

...Или ещё лучше получить массив такого вида:

```
Array
([21247] => "Сетевое оборудование > GOAL city"
 [20326] => "Контроль доступа > Считыватели > Komkom"
 [20400] => "Видеонаблюдение > Аналоговые видеокамеры > HikVision"
 [20618] => "Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ITV"
 [20619] => "Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ISS"
 [20620] => "Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > DSSL")
```

Пробовал через SimpleXML. Хотелось бы реализацию на PHP

Comment: на каком яп, на c#?

Comment: @Stack ..на PHP

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я написал, что пробовал использовать SimpleXML... получил некий результат ... но потом понял, что не понимаю, что дальше с ним делать... и что скорее всего копаю не туда

Comment: @cheh1 ну так напишите, что вы делали и куда накопали, может быть там все нормально и нужно только подправить

Comment: @cheh1 и кстати, почему нет промежуточных путей, типа `Источники питания > Аккумуляторы` или `Контроль доступа > Считыватели` ? почему только конечные?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всмысле промежуточный путь... вложенность указана в полном объёме! См. исходный XML

Comment: @cheh1 я имею в виду,почему нет пункта допустим `[20011] => "Источники питания > Аккумуляторы`? или `[20013] => "Контроль доступа > Считыватели` ? А если вложенность такая `Ударный инструмент > водонепроницаемый > жаростойкий > цепная тяга > стальной`, то по аналогии с примером не будут учитываться `Ударный инструмент > водонепроницаемый`, `Ударный инструмент > водонепроницаемый  > жаростойкий`,  `Ударный инструмент > водонепроницаемый  > жаростойкий > цепная тяга`.Вопрос:почему?Ведь на этих пунктах тоже должны быть крошки?Разве нет?Почему у вас в массиве указаны пути только до конечных узлов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский... все понял о чём Вы... цифры это обозначение категорий для конкретного товара... в описании товара есть номер категории и мне нужно просто вытащить цепочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pastebin.com/hXxbHVUw

Решение с классами, имхо, самое понятное и читаемое должно быть.

```
class XMLBreadcrumbCollection
{

    protected $elements = [];

    protected function build(&$categoriesList)
    {
        foreach ($categoriesList as $category)
        {
            if (empty($category['parentId']))
            {
                $this->add($category['id'], $category['parentId'], $category['name'], $categoriesList);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function add($id, $parent, $name, &$list)
    {
        $this->elements[] = new XMLBreadcrumb($id, $parent, $name, $list);
        return $this;
    }

    public function walk($callback, $current = null)
    {
        if (is_null($current))
        {
            $current = $this->elements;
        }

        foreach ($current as $element)
        {
            call_user_func($callback, $element);
            $this->walk($callback, $element->getChildren());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public static function parseCategories($xmlFileName)
    {
        $categoriesList = [];
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->load($xmlFileName);
        if ($dom)
        {
            $categories = $dom->getElementsByTagName('category');
            foreach ($categories as $category)
            {
                $categoriesList[] = [
                    'id'       => $category->getAttribute('id'),
                    'parentId' => $category->getAttribute('parentId'),
                    'name'     => $category->textContent,
                ];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Cant load xml file ' . $xmlFileName);
        }
        return $categoriesList;
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        return new static;
    }

    public static function parse($xmlFileName, $separator = ' > ')
    {
        $categoriesList = static::parseCategories($xmlFileName);
        $breadcrumbsArray = [];
        static::instance()
              ->build($categoriesList)
              ->walk(function ($element) use ($separator, &$breadcrumbsArray)
              {
                  if (!$element->haveChildren())
                  {
                      $breadcrumbsArray[$element->getId()] = $element->getName($separator);
                  }
              });
        return $breadcrumbsArray;
    }
}

class XMLBreadcrumb
{

    protected $id;
    protected $parentId;
    protected $name;

    protected $parent = null;
    protected $children = [];

    public function __construct($id, $parentId, $name, &$list)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->parentId = $parentId;
        $this->name = $name;

        foreach ($list as $category)
        {
            if (!empty($category['parentId']) && $category['parentId'] == $id)
            {
                $child = new static($category['id'], $category['parentId'], $category['name'], $list);
                $child->setParent($this);
                $this->children[] = $child;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function setParent(&$parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function getName($separator)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->parent))
        {
            $parent = $this->parent;
            return $parent->getName($separator) . $separator . $this->name;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }

    public function haveChildren()
    {
        return !empty($this->children);
    }

}

$breadcrumbs = XMLBreadcrumbCollection::parse(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.xml');

var_dump($breadcrumbs);
```

Вывод:

```
array (size=6)
  21247 => string 'Сетевое оборудование > GOAL city' (length=51)
  20326 => string 'Контроль доступа > Считыватели > Komkom' (length=65)
  20400 => string 'Видеонаблюдение > Аналоговые видеокамеры > HikVision' (length=88)
  20618 => string 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ITV' (length=66)
  20619 => string 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ISS' (length=66)
  20620 => string 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > DSSL' (length=67)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ... пришлось немного поправить под свою версию PHP 5.3.13

Answer (score 3):

Так как вы не указали язык, на котором вы хотели бы получить решение, предлагаю на питоне:

```
from lxml import etree 

def have_child(element, xml, tag): # проверка, есть ли у элемента "потомки"
    for i in xml.xpath('//{0}'.format(tag)):
        if 'parentId' in i.attrib and i.attrib['parentId'] == element.attrib['id']:
            return True
    return False


def create_path(element, xml, tag): # создать для element путь
    path_string = element.text
    while('parentId' in element.attrib):
        element = xml.xpath("//{0}[@id='{1}']".\
            format(tag, element.attrib['parentId']))[0]
        path_string = element.text + ' > ' + path_string
    return path_string

def get_dict(xml, tag): # вернет словарь с записями вида id: path

    result = {}
    for child in xml.xpath('//category[@parentId]'):
        if not have_child(child, xml, 'category'):
            result[child.attrib['id']] = create_path(child, xml, 'category')
    return result

def main(): # пример, как выглядит использование функции
    xml = etree.parse('test.xml')
    print(get_dict(xml, 'category'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

В результате получится словарь:

```
{   '20326': 'Контроль доступа > Считыватели > Komkom',
    '20400': 'Видеонаблюдение > Аналоговые видеокамеры > HikVision',
    '20618': 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ITV',
    '20619': 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > ISS',
    '20620': 'Источники питания > Аккумуляторы > DSSL',
    '21247': 'Сетевое оборудование > GOAL city'}
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, что не указал ЯП.. спасибо за ответ... но с питоном не знаком... так что не смогу по достоинству оценить ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Должно помочь:

```
$result= <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='WINDOWS-1251'?>
<categories>
    <category id="20001" >Сетевое оборудование</category>
    <category id="20002" >Контроль доступа</category>
    <category id="20003" >Видеонаблюдение</category>
    <category id="20004" >Источники питания</category>
    <category id="20011"  parentId="20004" >Аккумуляторы</category>
    <category id="20012"  parentId="20003" >Аналоговые видеокамеры</category>
    <category id="20013"  parentId="20002" >Считыватели</category>
    <category id="21247"  parentId="20001" >GOAL city</category>
    <category id="20326"  parentId="20013" >Komkom</category>
    <category id="20400"  parentId="20012" >HikVision</category>
    <category id="20618"  parentId="20011" >ITV</category>
    <category id="20619"  parentId="20011" >ISS</category>
    <category id="20620"  parentId="20011" >DSSL</category>
</categories>
XML;

$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $result);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($text);

$tree = [];
$count = count($xml);

/********************************************
* Функции для помощи в построениии крошек
*******************************************/
function haveChild($tree, $id) {
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if (isset($item['parentId']) && $item['parentId'] == $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;   
}


function buildBreadcrumbs($tree, $elem, $level) {

    $breadcrumbs = $elem['text'];
    if (isset($elem['parentId'])) {
        $item = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tree); ++$i) {
            if ($elem['parentId'] == $tree[$i]['id']) {
                $item = $tree[$i];              
                break;
            }               
        }

        $tmp = $breadcrumbs; 
        $arrow = ($level == 0 ? '' : ' > ' );
        $level = $level + 1;
        $breadcrumbs = buildBreadcrumbs($tree, $item, $level).$tmp.$arrow; 
        $level = $level - 1;        
    }

    return $breadcrumbs;
}

/**********************************************/


// формируем массив из xml структуры 
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {               
    $arr = [];
    $attr = $xml->category[$i]->attributes();       

    $arr['id'] = (int)$attr->id;
    $arr['parentId'] = (int)$attr->parentId;
    $arr['text'] = (string)$xml->category[$i];

    $tree[$i] = $arr;   
}

$breadcrumbsArray = [];
foreach ($tree as $item) {
    // Если у узла нет потомка, значит это крайний узел. 
    // Будем строить путь до него
    if (!haveChild($tree, $item['id'])) {
        $breadcrumbsArray[$item['id']] = buildBreadcrumbs($tree, $item, 0);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($breadcrumbsArray); 
//print_r($tree); 
echo '</pre>';
```

https://ideone.com/nx0xGc

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$text= <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='WINDOWS-1251'?>
<categories>
    <category id="20001" >Сетевое оборудование</category>
    <category id="20002" >Контроль доступа</category>
    <category id="20003" >Видеонаблюдение</category>
    <category id="20004" >Источники питания</category>
    <category id="20011"  parentId="20004" >Аккумуляторы</category>
    <category id="20012"  parentId="20003" >Аналоговые видеокамеры</category>
    <category id="20013"  parentId="20002" >Считыватели</category>
    <category id="21247"  parentId="20001" >GOAL city</category>
    <category id="20326"  parentId="20013" >Komkom</category>
    <category id="20400"  parentId="20012" >HikVision</category>
    <category id="20618"  parentId="20011" >ITV</category>
    <category id="20619"  parentId="20011" >ISS</category>
    <category id="20620"  parentId="20011" >DSSL</category>
</categories>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string(iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $text));

function createBreadcrumbs($xml){
    $elements = [];
    $parents = [];
    if(isset($xml->category)){
        /** @var SimpleXMLElement $category */
        foreach($xml->category as $category){
            $attr = $category->attributes();
            $elements[(int)$attr->id] = [
                'parent_id'=>(int)$attr->parentId,
                'text'=>(string)$category
            ];
            if(!empty((int)$attr->parentId)){
                $parents[]=(int)$attr->parentId;
            }
        }
    }
    $parents = array_unique($parents);
    $response = [];
    foreach($elements as $id=>$element){
        if(!in_array($id, $parents)){
            $way = recursiveBread($elements, $element);
            krsort($way);
            $response[$id] = implode(' > ', $way);
        }
    }
    return $response;
}

function recursiveBread($elements, $element, $data=[]){
    $parent_id = $element['parent_id'];
    $data[] = $element['text'];
    if($elements[$parent_id]['parent_id']){
        $data = recursiveBread($elements, $elements[$parent_id], $data);
    }else{
        $data[] = $elements[$parent_id]['text'];
    }
    return $data;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(createBreadcrumbs($xml));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree 

def have_child(element, xml, tag): # проверка, есть ли у элемента "потомки"
    for i in xml.xpath('//{0}'.format(tag)):
        if 'parentId' in i.attrib and i.attrib['parentId'] == element.attrib['id']:
            return True
    return False


def create_path(element, xml, tag): # создать для element путь
    path_string = element.text
    while('parentId' in element.attrib):
        element = xml.xpath("//{0}[@id='{1}']".\
            format(tag, element.attrib['parentId']))[0]
        path_string = element.text + ' > ' + path_string
    return path_string

def get_dict(xml, tag): # вернет словарь с записями вида id: path

    result = {}
    for child in xml.xpath('//category[@parentId]'):
        if not have_child(child, xml, 'category'):
            result[child.attrib['id']] = create_path(child, xml, 'category')
    return result

def main(): # пример, как выглядит использование функции
    xml = etree.parse('test.xml')
    print(get_dict(xml, 'category'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Позволю себе переложить на php, так как ответ очень правильные по сравнению с рекурсями и тучей циклов..

```
class lxml {

    public function __construct($stringXml) {
       $xmlDom = simplexml_load_string($stringXml);
       $breadcrums = $this->get_dict($xmlDom,'category');
       print_r($breadcrums);
    }

    public function get_dict($xml,$tag) {
       $result = array();
       foreach(xml.xpath('//category[@parentId]') as $child) {
          if(!$this->have_child($child,$xml,$tag)) {
             $result[$child->attributes()['id']] = create_path($child,$xml,$tag);
          }
       }
       return $result;
    }

    public function create_path($element,$xml,$tag) {
       $path_string = $element->category;
       while(isset($element->attribute()['parentId'])) {
          $element = xml.xpath(sprint_f("//%s[@id='%s']",$tag, $element->attributes['parentId']))[0];
          $path_string = $element->category.' > '.$path_string;
       }
    }

    public function have_child($element,$xml,$tag) {
       foreach($xml->xpath(sprint_f('//%s',$tag)) as $_checkElement) {
          if(isset($_checkElement->attribute()['parentId'])) {
             if($_checkElement->attribute()['parentId'] == $element->attributes['id']) {
               return true;
             } 
          }
       }
      return false;
    }

}
```

В общем ответ очен правильный так как алгоритм лишён, бесмысленого перебора элементов он просто ищет нужное. @Flowneee (ваш/его) ответ достоин награды...

Comment: ответ ваш нравиться... вот только как использовать эту красоту...можно примерчик?

Comment: @cheh1 Ну это не мой ответ это ответ Flowneee который написал на питоне я лишь переложил. Всё просто берете клас вызываете `new lxml($stringXmlFromFile)` и передаёте в него фаил.